# Centralizing Post Data on the client and server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.5

I'm building my first API and I have this nightmare scenario where I see myself defining the same request data in multiples places. How are people maintaining their key/value payloads?

Here's my VueJS component on the client side:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: '', 
                description: '',
                selectedHeader: '',
            }
        },
        computed: {
            businessUrl() {
                return this.name.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, '') + '.test.com';
            },
        },
        methods: {
            preview() {
                let data = {
                    'name': this.businessUrl,
                    'description' : this.description,
                    'selectedHeader': this.selectedHeader
                };

                axios.post('/builder/preview', data)
        ...
</script>
```

Server-side:

```
public function preview()
{
    $validatedData = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'string',
        'selectedHeader' => 'required',
    ]);

    $business = new Business; 
    $business->name = request('name');
    $business->description = request('description');
    $business->header = request('selectedHeader');

    return view('business', compact('business'));
}
```

If I want to change the 'name' field that is posted on my route I have to do it in up to 5 places if I include references in my HTML. Any patterns that people have developed to avoid this duplication?

Comment: I'd draw inspiration from angular's resource pattern: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/894 or https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-resources

Comment: Can't really understand what you require to do / what is the problem

Comment: Well for one: I would try and keep my api definition as fixed as possible; when changin something in the internal structure of the database, you can still keep the api the same.  Basically I believe you should consider your laravel and vuejs as two seperate applications that communicate through the api.  The logical consequence is that you would have to change it on both ends if changes to the API are required.